# No suitable conversion error using while using std::sort in c++

Tags: c++

```
bool COMPARE(const void * i, const void * j) 
{ return (((clPoint*)i)->x() - ((clPoint*)j)->x()); }


std::vector<clPoint> iFillPoints;


std::sort(iFillPoints.begin(), iFillPoints.end(), COMPARE);
```

i get this error when i run this

```
Error   16  error : no suitable conversion function from "Pixel" to "const void *" exists
```

Comment: We miss something from your code. Where is Pixel defined ?

Comment: template<typename Type>
class PointGeneric
{
public:

Comment: The comparison function should take in input const Pixel*;
Or better the same type of iFillPoints

Comment: not sure why i am getting pixel error , i am a beginner in c++, here is the declaration and definition of clpoint                          template<typename Type>
class PointGeneric
{
public:   PointGeneric
        (
        Type x,
        Type y
        );  };                                                                                                                      typedef PointGeneric<SemInt32> clPoint;

Answer (score 2):

Your `compare` function should probably look more like

```
bool COMPARE(const clPoint& i, const clPoint& j) 
{ return i.x() < j.x(); }
```

The `std::sort` algorithm will pass in elements of the container, which are `clPoint`, not pointers (and certainly not void pointers). You can accept the `clPoint` objects by reference instead of value. This also removes the need to cast away from void pointers.

The function should be returning a `bool`; `i.x() - j.x()`, which you originally had, is probably an `int` or a `double`, not a `bool`, so won't be helpful. These are converted to `bool` as `false` for a 0 value, and `true` otherwise: so your function would return `false` when the inputs were equal, and `true` otherwise, which is not at all what a comparison function for `std::sort` should look like. The less-than operator gives the right semantics.

M.M. raises a good point in the comments—this won't work if the `x()` method of `clPoint` wasn't declared `const`, so make sure it is (the signature within the class declaration of `PointGeneric` should like something like `Type x() const;`.)

Comment: For good design, the comparator should be `const`  (may require `x()` to be made `const` too, if OP overlooked to do that)